Removing Whitespace Around Clickable Div
I am trying to create a clickable div, but there is whitespace to the left and right.

I've tried making it an inline-block but all it does is shift the button to the left. I need it to remain centered.
The code for this is:
<a href="google.com">
<div style="margin:auto;display:block;font-size:20px;font-weight:100;border-radius:8px;background-color: #34ac00;padding:16px;color:white;text-align:center;width:200px">Quit Drinking Now
</div>
</a>

Any clarity would remain appreciated.

The most straightforward way to achieve what you are seeking is to wrap your block in a flexbox <div>, as such:
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
  <a href="google.com">
    <div style="(omitted for the purpose of this example)">
      Quit Drinking Now
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

This will allow you to have a clickable <div> whilst also not being able to click the whitespace around it.

How did you know to use a flexbox?

Your <div>, originally, was taking up the entire width of the page. By putting it inside of a parent <div>, it would be able to retain its original width and so the whitespace would not count as a clickable area. A screen-wide flexbox as the parent <div> would allow for centering without the child being as wide as the screen. Hope this clarifies things better for you!
